# Performance of JToken.FromObject vs default behavior in Json.net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Following the sample here:
http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

I am wondering how `JToken.FromObject` impacs performance when serialization.

Hoping someone have an asnwer and save me the time of profiling it after doing it.

I have a custom class where I would like to alter the values in the serialization and the sample seems to be a good case to do so. Just wondering if its using extra reflection to do so or `JToken.FromObject` also is used internally when serializing an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The great thing about OSS is that you can actually see everything yourself:

From the [JToken class](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JToken.cs)

```
internal static JToken FromObjectInternal(object o, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer)
{
     ValidationUtils.ArgumentNotNull(o, "o");
     ValidationUtils.ArgumentNotNull(jsonSerializer, "jsonSerializer");

     JToken token;
     using (JTokenWriter jsonWriter = new JTokenWriter())
     {
         jsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, o);
         token = jsonWriter.Token;
     }

     return token;
}
```

There isn't any reflection overhead, just the extra allocation of `JTokenWriter` which is passed to `JsonSerializer`.